# Bash Format HEX string

Tags: bash, shell, string, formatting

Anyone know a standard unix command to format a running SHA1 hex string like this:

```
344F9DA1EA1859437077CCA38923C67797BDB8F6
```

into this:

```
344F9DA1 EA185943 7077CCA3 8923C677 97BDB8F6
```

Like:

```
echo "344F9DA1EA1859437077CCA38923C67797BDB8F6" | awk ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one option with `sed`:

```
echo "344F9DA1EA1859437077CCA38923C67797BDB8F6" | sed -E 's/.{8}/& /g'
```

(replace any sequence of 8 characters by itself plus one space)

Comment: Nice. But I forgot to mention I'm on OSX, and SED doesn't seem to have a `-r` flag. Any tips?

Comment: You probably don't need the -r, but points for a shorter command to Martin!

Comment: Changed it to `sed -E 's/[0-9A-F]{8}/& /g'` which seems to work on both OSX and my Linux box

Comment: @Hugo: Just add lots of backslashes for things that don't work. Also, & is the traditional way to refer to the whole match. Maybe something similar to `s/[0-9A-F]\{8\}/& /g` ? No OSX here.

Comment: -r is non-standard.  For portability, you can do: sed -e 's/\\(.\{8\}\\)/\1 /g'

Comment: Strange... sed -E 's/[0-9A-F]{8}/& /g' is outputing `344f9da1ea18594370 77cca38923c67797bdb8f6`. And switching to {4} makes even less sense: `344f9da1ea1859 4370 77cca3892 3c6779 7bdb8f6`. Pursell's answer solves the problem, though :-)

Comment: @Hugo: You didn't mention they could be lower case :) Pattern should then be: `sed -E 's/[0-9A-Fa-z]{8}/& /g'`  or simply `sed -E 's/.{8}/& /g'`. Updated answer again.

Answer (score 4):

To add a space after every eighth character, try:

If the contents are on a single line in a file named `FILENAME`:

```
sed 's/.\{8\}/& /g' FILENAME
```

Or, if they're split across multiple lines.  Again, for a file named `FILENAME`:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;s/\n//;ba;};s/.\{8\}/& /g' FILENAME
```

To illustrate the difference:

```
ezra@ubuntu:~$ cat test.file
344F9DA1EA1859437077CCA38923C67797BDB8F6
344F9DA1EA1859437077

ezra@ubuntu:~$ sed ':a;$!{N;s/\n//;ba;};s/.\{8\}/& /g' test.file
344F9DA1 EA185943 7077CCA3 8923C677 97BDB8F6 344F9DA1 EA185943 7077

ezra@ubuntu:~$ sed 's/.\{8\}/& /g' test.file
344F9DA1 EA185943 7077CCA3 8923C677 97BDB8F6
344F9DA1 EA185943 7077
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in bash without piping at all.

```
bash$ FOO="344F9DA1EA1859437077CCA38923C67797BDB8F6"
bash$ echo ${FOO:0:8} ${FOO:8:8} ${FOO:16:8} ${FOO:24:8} ${FOO:32:8}
344F9DA1 EA185943 7077CCA3 8923C677 97BDB8F6
```

Comment: good - and with no trailing space ...also:  `eval echo \${FOO:{0..4}*8:8}`

Answer (score 2):

Another one:

```
echo "344F9DA1EA1859437077CCA38923C67797BDB8F6" | fold -b8 | tr "\n" " "
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
echo "344F9DA1EA1859437077CCA38923C67797BDB8F6" \
| awk '{
    printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n", 
      substr($0,1,8),  substr($0,9,8), substr($0,17,8), substr($0,25,8),
      substr($0,33,8), substr($0,41,8)    )
    }
 '
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Don't know about OSX 's awk, but in GNU awk: `echo "344F9DA1EA1859437077CCA38923C67797BDB8F6" | awk --posix '{gsub("([0-9A-F]){8}","& ");print}'`.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure Bash (version 3.2 or greater):

```
hex=344F9DA1EA1859437077CCA38923C67797BD
p='(.{8})'; unset patt; for i in {1..5}; do patt+=$p; done
[[ $hex =~ $patt ]]
string=${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}
echo "$string"    # output: 344F9DA1 EA185943 7077CCA3 8923C677 97BDB8F6
```